# Can I change datatype list to bs4.element.ResultSet?

Tags: python, pandas, api, beautifulsoup

I wanted to get data from 2022-01 to 2022-04,
so I used this code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df = []

for i in month:
    gu_code = 11680 
    numOfRows=1000
    month = [202201, 202202, 220203, 202204]
    
    url = "http://openapi.molit.go.kr:8081/OpenAPI_ToolInstallPackage/service/rest/RTMSOBJSvc/getRTMSDataSvcAptTrade?LAWD_CD="+str(gu_code)+"&DEAL_YMD="+ str(i) +"&numOfRows="+str(numOfRows)+"&serviceKey="+str(ServiceKey)
    result = urlopen(url) 
    house = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml-xml')
    te = house.find_all('item')
    df.append(te)
```

after this, I used this code but the problem is df is the list. and len(df) is 4.

```
data = []

for i in range(k):
    month = df[i].월.string.strip()
    price = df[i].거래금액.string.strip()
    
    built_yr = df[i].건축년도.string.strip()
    
    dong_name = df[i].법정동.string.strip()
    apt_name = df[i].아파트.string.strip()
    size = df[i].전용면적.string.strip()
    gu_code = df[i].지역코드.string.strip()
    
    total = [dong_name, apt_name, price, month, built_yr, size, gu_code ]
    data.append(total)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
```

Or a better way to do that is change your df list to a different variable, and iterate through that:

Note, your loop makes no sense. You are iterating through a list that is defined inside the loop. So I changed it to make sens, but have no idea what you are doing:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df_list = []


gu_code = 11680 
numOfRows=1000
month = [202201, 202202, 220203, 202204]

for i in month:

    
    url = "http://openapi.molit.go.kr:8081/OpenAPI_ToolInstallPackage/service/rest/RTMSOBJSvc/getRTMSDataSvcAptTrade?LAWD_CD="+str(gu_code)+"&DEAL_YMD="+ str(i) +"&numOfRows="+str(numOfRows)+"&serviceKey="+str(ServiceKey)
    result = urlopen(url) 
    house = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml-xml')
    te = house.find_all('item')
    df_list.append(te)
```

Then:

```
data = []

for df in df_list:
    month = df[i].월.string.strip()
    price = df[i].거래금액.string.strip()
    
    built_yr = df[i].건축년도.string.strip()
    
    dong_name = df[i].법정동.string.strip()
    apt_name = df[i].아파트.string.strip()
    size = df[i].전용면적.string.strip()
    gu_code = df[i].지역코드.string.strip()
    
    total = [dong_name, apt_name, price, month, built_yr, size, gu_code ]
    data.append(total)
```

Comment: I wanna get a data from OpenAPI so I need to change value "&DEAL_YMD=". So I try to use loop 202201, 202202, 202203, 202204.

Comment: right, but you are trying to loop through a list that is inside of the loop.

Comment: Ahh I got it. Thx.